# How to run an executable from a Windows Service Written in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I attempted to execute wsl.exe with a specific Linux command within my Windows Service written in C#. However, each time I encounter the error message (in my log file):`The file cannot be accessed by the system.` 
I have installed and run the service using both the LocalSystem user and my personal user account, but it did not work. Strangely, when I run the code within my IDE and with the same personal user account set in the service, it works perfectly. I have also provided the full path to the wsl executable, but the issue persists. In summary, when the code is run by the service as LocalSystem or as my personal user, it does not work. However, when I run the program myself, it works seamlessly. Thank you for reading and assisting me! 
Here's below the code that my Windows Service is running :

```
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "wsl.exe",
                Arguments = "ls",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };

        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Output received: {e.Data}");
            }
        };

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error received: {e.Data}");
            }
        };
        process.Exited += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Process exited with code: {process.ExitCode}");
        };
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Did you already search for this error message? I get a lot of useful hits, like https://superuser.com/questions/1714397/wsl-2-0-the-file-cannot-be-accessed-by-the-system or https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9197

Comment: I tried to run the command  : "dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" and to reset WSL2 but did not work unfortunately. however when I run wsl.exe in cmd it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, that was simply to update wsl, by using the command `wsl --update`